# Data Attribute en un boton en un JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Buenas tardes a todos.

Se puede agregar un data attribute a un boton que se encuentra en un JSP.
Esta es la estructura que tengo:

```
"<html:submit styleClass="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Obtener datos"/>"
```

Pero no logro ponerle un data attribute como en html.

Gracias.

Comment: Esta es mi estructura: <html:submit styleClass="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Obtener datos"/>

Comment: Agrega el codigo a la pregunta original, puedes usar el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/268288/edit) al final de la pregunta